# Cast ConcurrentHashMap<String, B> to ConcurrentHashMap<String, A> when B implements A

Tags: java, casting, concurrenthashmap

I have an interface called `SerializableL` that is implemented by 3 different classes:

- Product
- Banner
- Tag

I started refactoring and wanted to replace multiple paragraphs with multiple method calls.

```
public void load(ConcurrentHashMap<String, SerializableL> map, 
ArrayList<SerializableForL> preparedList)
```

I've written the following code and get the following error.

**Code:**

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, SerializableForL> test = DBStore.Cache.get(tag);
```

**Error:**

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ConcurrentHashMap<String,Banner> to 
    ConcurrentHashMap<String,SerializableForL>
```

**How can I do a workaround?**

I want a way to cast (`ConcurrentHashMap<String,Banner>` to 
        `ConcurrentHashMap<String,SerializableForL>`) .

A banner IS a SerializableForL.

Comment: The error is correct.  The compiler doesn't think that is a safe operation for good reason.  If you know it shouldn't be a problem you can use type erasure and cast it to a `(ConcurrentHashMap)`

Comment: @ Peter Lawrey How would I do that?

Comment: `ConcurrentHashMap<String, SerializableForL> test = (ConcurrentHashMap) DBStore.Cache.get(tag);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't assign a `Map<String,Banner>` to a `Map<String,SerializableForL>` [even if `Banner` implements `SerializableForL`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p).

However, if you only care about the values being `SerializableForL` you should be able to write:

```
ConcurrentMap<String, ? extends SerializableForL> test = DBStore.Cache.get(tag);
```

Comment: +1 This is seriously some dark sorcery.... Sometimes problems like these make me want to go be a stripper heh.